# Find the least value of $n$ for which $A_n$ contains an element of order $15$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know how to find the smallest $n$ in $S_n$ with order $15$ but I'm not sure how to go about it in $A_n$. Thank you.

Comment: What is this question even *about*??

Comment: Well, $S_n$ injects into $A_{n+2}$ so if you have the minimal result for $S_n$ you have a candidate for the minimal result in $A_n$.  Once you have that, then it should just be a question of showing that smaller cases do not work.

Comment: $x$ is the order of *what* ?

Comment: As you can see from the comments, your post is not clear.  I take it that your question is "find the least $n$ for which the alternating group $A_n$ has an element of order $15$".  The bit about the symmetric and alternating groups being the same is hard to follow and I don't think you meant it the way it reads.  But, please edit for clarity.

Comment: Perhaps "I know how to find the least $n$ such that $S_n$ contains an element of order $15$."  (You've currently claimed that there is an $n$ such that $S_n$ has order $15$, which ... is very unlikely.)

Comment: Every element of odd order in $S_n$ is actually in $A_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You know

1. the prime factorization of $15$ is $3 \cdot 5$,
2. the only elements of $S_n$ (any $n$) of order $3$ are $3$-cycles and of order $5$ are $5$-cycles,
3. $A_n$ contains (among other cycle patterns) cycles of odd length, so $A_n$ automatically contains all the $3$- and $5$-cycles of $S_n$ and, since $A_n$ is a group, the products of such cycles,
4. two cycles commute if they are disjoint,
5. the order of $xy$ where $x$ has order $3$, $y$ has order $5$, and $x$ and $y$ commute is $15$.  So certainly, there is an element of $A_{3+5}$ that is the product of a $3$-cycle with a disjoint $5$-cycle.  So we need only show there is no element of order $15$ in $A_n$ for $n < 8$.
6. If $n < 5$, $A_n$ has no $5$-cycle, so has no element of order $15$.  So we only need to show there is no element of order $15$ in $A_n$ for $n \geq 5$.

This just leaves checking (by some method) each of $A_5$, $A_6$, and $A_7$ for an element of order $15$.  If you check in that order, if you find one, you have found the minimal $n$.  If you don't find one in that list of groups, then you know there is one in $A_8$, for example $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)(6\,7\,8)$ (with many, many more examples available).